# If you roll four fair dice, what is the probability that you will end up with two 1's and two 3's?

Tags: probability, statistics, dice

Can someone help me with this? I'm completely stumped on how to go about it and no one I know can help. I just need to be shown how to do it.

Comment: What do you know about probability?

Comment: I know a bit, but apparently not enough because I can't figure this problem out. Thanks.

Comment: If you know a bit, could you try to post some sort of solution?

Comment: @IanColey your comments aren't particularly helpful.  OP has already expressed that they have no idea where to start.  The best way to respond, if you're worried about giving too much to be helpful, is to give the smallest possible nudge in the right direction.

Comment: The only thing I could think of is I know the total possible outcome is 6^4 = 1296. After that I'm stumped on where to go. I thought maybe since there's 4 1's and you roll two of them, that means it's half, same goes for the three. I honestly am so lost...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability of an event is the number of "successful outcomes" over the number of possible outcomes.  Since you have correctly stated that there are $6^4$ potential outcomes, let's try to count the number of outcomes that are "successful", i.e. contain two 1's and two 3's.

If we roll four dice, the "successful" outcomes are

- $3,3,1,1$
- $3,1,3,1$
- $1,3,3,1$
- $3,1,1,3$
- $1,3,1,3$
- $1,1,3,3$

That is, there are $6$ successful outcomes out of the $6^4$ possibilities.

If we wanted to approach the above systematically, we could note that any valid possibility can be created by selecting $2$ out of the $4$ dice to land on $1$, and setting the other dice to land on $3$.  Thus, there would be $\binom{4}{2} = \frac{4!}{2!2!}=6$ successful outcomes.

Comment: So would it then be 6/1296 or 1/216?

Comment: That's exactly right!

Comment: Thank you so much!! You've been extremely helpful, I understand now.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You are correct that the total outcomes are $1296$.  The number of successful outcomes is the number of ways of listing two $1$'s and two $3$'s in a row.  You can do that by hand, or find  the number of ways to choose which two of the four positions have $1$'s in them.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not sure how to list them. Is there any way someone can show me an example of a similar problem, and how to solve it, and then I can apply it to mine? So far I have found none.